# Array of FILE* through functions: FILE* or FILE**?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I'm trying to make a program which can work with several different files at the same time. My idea is to make an array of 20 FILE* in order to, if ever I arrive to this limit, to be able of closing one of them and open the new file requested. 
    For this purpose I've thought in a function that selects an option and calls another that makes the job of saving (writing), closing and opening.
    After half week of searching through the web and making some proves, I've made two versions that seem to work: one with FILE* and another with FILE**.

My question is: if some of them has a mistake that I can't detect or a bad use of pointers when passing through these two functions.

(The code I display have the two versions of the two functions one after another.)

```
MyProgram() {

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/* The contents of myFile1a.dat, myFile2b.dat,... are just 5 ints. */


/* Version without pointer to pointer. */
void fReadFile(FILE* pfFile[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int iNums[15] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int iNums2[15] = {5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 2033, 2066, 2099, 2133, 2166, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005};
    char cNameFile4d[32] = "myFile4d.dat", cNameFile5e[32] = "myFile5e.dat";   
    char cNameFile6f[32] = "myFile6f.dat";
    char cNameFile[32] = {" "};
    int iResultFclose = 0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[0]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=5; i<10; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[1]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=10; i<15; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[2]);
        printf("\n%d", iNums[i]);
    }

    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 1.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 2.");

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile4d);
    pfFile[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, pfFile[0]);
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile5e);
    pfFile[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=5; i<10; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, pfFile[1]);
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile6f);
    pfFile[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=10; i<15; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, pfFile[2]);

    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 1.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 2.");

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile4d);
    pfFile[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile5e);
    pfFile[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile6f);
    pfFile[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[0]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=5; i<10; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[1]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=10; i<15; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pfFile[2]);
        printf("\n%d", iNums[i]);
    }

    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pfFile[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
}

/* Version with pointer to pointer. */
void fReadFile(FILE** pfFile[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    int iNums[15] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int iNums2[15] = {5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 2033, 2066, 2099, 2133, 2166, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005};
    char cNameFile4d[32] = "myFile4d.dat", cNameFile5e[32] = "myFile5e.dat", cNameFile6f[32] = "myFile6f.dat";
    char cNameFile[32] = {" "};
    int iResultFclose = 0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[0]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=5; i<10; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[1]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=10; i<15; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[2]);
        printf("\n%d", iNums[i]);
    }

    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 1.");
        iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 2.");

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile4d);
    (*pfFile)[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[0]);
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile5e);
    (*pfFile)[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=5; i<10; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[1]);
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile6f);
    (*pfFile)[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "wb");
    for(i=10; i<15; i++)
        fwrite(&iNums2[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[2]);

    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 1.");
    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 2.");

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile4d);
    (*pfFile)[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile5e);
    (*pfFile)[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile6f);
    (*pfFile)[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[0]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=5; i<10; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[1]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=10; i<15; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, (*pfFile)[2]);
        printf("\n%d", iNums[i]);
    }

    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose((*pfFile)[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
}

/* Version without "&" in the caller. */
void fOptions(FILE* pfFileOpc[], int option) {
    int i = 0;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1: {fReadFile(pfFileOpc); break;}
        case 2: {printf("\nHello!\n"); break;}
        default: break;
    }
}

/* Version with "&" in the caller. */
void fOptions(FILE* pfFileOpc[], int option) {
    int i = 0;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1: {fReadFile(&pfFileOpc); break;}
        case 2: {printf("\nHello!\n"); break;}
        default: break;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *pFile[3];
    int i = 0, j = 0, option = 0, iResultFclose = 0;

    char cNameFile[32] = {" "};
    char cNameFile1a[32] = "myFile1a.dat", cNameFile2b[32] = "myFile2b.dat";
    char cNameFile3c[32] = "myFile3c.dat", cNameFile4d[32] = "myFile4d.dat";
    char cNameFile5e[32] = "myFile5e.dat",  cNameFile6f[32] = "myFile6f.dat";

    int iNums[15] = {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2033, 2066, 2099,  2133, 2166, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005};
    int iNums2[15] = {5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 2033, 2066, 2099,  2133, 2166, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005};

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile1a);
    pFile[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[0])
        puts("Error opening the file1a");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile2b);
    pFile[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[1])
        puts("Error opening the file2b");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile3c);
    pFile[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[2])
        puts("Error opening the file3c");

    printf("\nWrite an option: \n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    fOptions(pFile, option);

    puts("\n\nAnd we foooooolow....... \n\n");

    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile1a);
    pFile[0] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[0])
        puts("Error opening the file1a");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile2b);
    pFile[1] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[1])
        puts("Error opening the file2b");
    strcpy(cNameFile, cNameFile3c);
    pFile[2] = fopen(cNameFile, "rb");
    if (!pFile[2])
        puts("Error opening the file3c");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pFile[0]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=5; i<10; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pFile[1]);
        printf("\n%d",iNums[i]);
    }
    for(i=10; i<15; i++) {
        fread(&iNums[i], 4, 1, pFile[2]);
        printf("\n%d", iNums[i]);
    }

    iResultFclose = fclose(pFile[0]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 0.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pFile[1]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 1.");
    iResultFclose = fclose(pFile[2]);
    if (iResultFclose != 0)
        puts("Error closing the file 2.");

    return 0;
}
```

}

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Compile and debug to see any error .

Comment: Are you asking for a review of the code to help you diagnose potential problems?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would use a `(FILE **)[]` for this.  A `(FILE *)[]` should be perfectly adequate.  As for examining your code for problems, you've posted in the wrong place.  You want http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I haven't read the code, but notice that `FILE* pfFile[]` is equivalent to `FILE **pfFile`, which is basically a pointer to a pointer to a FILE (a 2D FILE array). And `FILE** pfFile[]` is a 3D array.

Comment: Basically an array of FILE pointers should be all you need.

Comment: AmeyCU, I have compiled and tested and gives no warning or error. R Sahu, yes I would like help to diagnose potential problems, as I'would like to know if my c level is enough. What I mean is, as you add a level of pointer every time you send a reference to a function, e.g. if you have *pPerson, inside a function you will add a level of pointer (**pPerson). I was thinking that if I have FIILE * pMyFiles[3] (the first pointer is beacause the standard and the [3] because I want 3), then, using it inside a function, SHOULD I add a level of pointer every time I call a function from inside another?

Comment: R Sahu, I've just discovered an answer you gave the  3th october 2014 to the question " Returning multiple file pointers in C ". I think it could be a solution if I can't understand my pointers problem.

Answer (score 2):

A single file handle is a pointer to `FILE`, i.e., `FILE *`. Since you want an array of these `FILE *` elements, the pointer to the array is `FILE **arr`, which is equivalent to `FILE *arr[]` when used as the type of a parameter to a function.

Comment: It is equivalent when array-to-pointer conversions take place, otherwise they're two different types.